# Why is MySQL not considering a (JSON) functional index in a join, but an index on a generated column is considered?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, functional-index

I am using `JSON` columns a lot in MySQL (version 8.0.35). Usually, I create functional indexes on JSON properties to speed up queries. According to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts), *Functional indexes are implemented as hidden virtual generated columns*. However, they seem to behave differently from indexes on generated columns in joins. I will use a somehow constructed example to explain my point.

Example: Given are two tables `product` and `purchase`. `purchase` has a JSON property `$.productUuid` that references a `product`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    id         BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    payload    JSON       NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase (
    id         BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    payload    JSON       NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX `i_purchase_product` (
        ( CAST(payload->>'$.productUuid' AS CHAR(36)) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin )
    )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO product (id, payload)
VALUES
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), '{ "name": "random drink" }' ),
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), '{ "name": "random dish" }' ),
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), '{ "name": "random tool" }' )
;

INSERT INTO purchase (id, payload)
SELECT
  UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), JSON_SET(payload, '$.productUuid', BIN_TO_UUID(id))
FROM product
;
```

For the following query

```sql
SELECT * FROM product a INNER JOIN purchase b ON BIN_TO_UUID(a.id) = b.payload->>'$.productUuid';
```

MySQL generates the following plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | possible_keys | key  | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL          | NULL | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL          | NULL | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The plan shows that the functional index is not even considered. The case is different if I create the table with a generated column and a regular index on it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase (
    id           BINARY(16)  NOT NULL,
    payload      JSON        NOT NULL,
    product_uuid VARCHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (payload->>'$.productUuid') STORED NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_purchase PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX `i_purchase_product` (product_uuid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Now, the plan generated by MySQL is showing that the index is considered:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | possible_keys      | key                | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL               | NULL               | NULL                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | i_purchase_product | i_purchase_product | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Is there an explanation, preferrably documented, for this behavior?

Comment: What if you don't use `CAST()` in the functional index? That's not the same as the generated column.

Comment: @Barmar `CAST()` is required as `JSON_UNQUOTE()` (`->>` is shorthand for `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))`) returns data type `LONGTEXT` and MySQL cannot index those without specifying a prefix length ([Functional Key Parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts)). It raises error code 3757.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98937

It's not even about the use of JSON. Any functional index cannot be used in a JOIN, even if the same index can be used in another condition.

I modified your example to use an arbitrary string function instead of using JSON functions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    id         BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    abc CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase (
    id         BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    abc CHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX `i_abc` ((REVERSE(abc)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO product (id, abc)
VALUES
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), 'abc' ),
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), 'abc' ),
  ( UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO purchase (id, abc)
SELECT
  UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE),  REVERSE(abc)
FROM product;
```

Searching using the expression of the functional index works as expected, it utilizes the index:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM purchase b WHERE REVERSE(b.abc) = 'abc';

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ref  | i_abc         | i_abc | 15      | const |    3 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

But joining using the expression of the functional index does not use the index:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM product a
INNER JOIN purchase b
ON REVERSE(b.abc) = a.abc;

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The bug was reported in March 2020 (over three years ago as we write this). The only resolution was that they agreed to "file a documentation bug to clarify the current limitations." But then they linked to an internal bug (not visible to me).

So far, I have not found that they document this limitation.